# Unable to get dominant colour of image using Microsoft's Computer Vision

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure

I've been stuck on this problem for a while.
I'm trying to get the dominant colour of an image using Microsoft's Computer Vision service.
An extract of my code is below:

```
import {VisualFeatureTypes} from "@azure/cognitiveservices-computervision/esm/models";
...

let visualFeatures: VisualFeatureTypes[] = ['Color'];
const caption = (await computerVisionClient.analyzeImageInStream(describeURL, visualFeatures));
```

Doing a `console.log(caption)` returns the following JSON object:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "name": "others_",
      "score": 0.15625
    }
  ],
  "requestId": "5a24115f-8095-4a77-8aa9-2d719dce99e6",
  "metadata": {
    "width": 500,
    "height": 500,
    "format": "Jpeg"
  }
}
```

The Computer Vision service definitely works, because if I change the method from `analyzeImageInStream` to `describeImageInStream` and remove, then I get the appropriate response.

For testing, I've been using this image [here](https://rayc.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/RAYC-Cotton-TShirt.jpg), and using Computer Vision's [Demo](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/). The demo returns colour information, but my API call does not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on the result, the service didn't get your "visualFeatures" parameter.

Comment: Yes, I assume so as well. Any idea why that may be the case?

Comment: Can you check the HTTP request header in the dev console?

Comment: The request header is something like `https://....cognitiveservices.azure.com/vision/v3.0/analyze?language=en`. It should have something like `visualFeatures=Categories,Description,Color` according to this link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp-analyze). This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/vision-api-how-to-topics/howtocallvisionapi) has exactly what I need, but its in C#. I tried my best to do what it does but in Javascript, but I don't know why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this doc, you should put the params in your url. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/javascript-analyze

```
const urlBase = "https://....cognitiveservices.azure.com/vision/v3.0/analyze";
var params = {
        "visualFeatures": "Categories,Description,Color",
        "details": "",
        "language": "en",
    };

$.ajax({
        url: uriBase + "?" + $.param(params),
        // Request headers.
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader(
                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
        },
        type: "POST",
        // Request body.
        data: '{"url": ' + '"' + sourceImageUrl + '"}',
    }) .done(function(data) {
        // Show formatted JSON on webpage.
        callYourFunction(data);
    })
```